# Can't select nth-child div

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to move some divs around, however I can't seem to select them just getting through object object:

http://jsfiddle.net/kL3c8/1/

```
<div class="partnerGroupContent">
   <div class="column"> 
        <div class="sponsor">1</div>
        <div class="sponsor">2</div>
   </div>
    <div class="column1"> 
        <div class="sponsor">3</div>
        <div class="sponsor">4</div>
   </div>
</div>

var rowCount = 2

var myColumn = $('.partnerGroupContent:nth-child(2)')

if (rowCount == 2) {

$('.partnerGroupContent').after('<div class="partnerGroupContent2">' + myColumn + '</div>');

}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are concatenating a jQuery object to a string, it doesn't work that way. And you have misunderstood `:nth-child`. It is a filter that filters elements in the set that are `nth` child of their parent, so you probably want this:

```
$('.partnerGroupContent > :nth-child(2)')
```

And

```
$('.partnerGroupContent').after(
    $('<div>', {
        'class': 'partnerGroupContent2'
    }).append(myColumn) //append the actual element
                    //don't concatenate strings
)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kL3c8/6/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: `$('.partnerGroupContent:nth-child(2))` is not returning anything.

Use: `var myColumn = $('.partnerGroupContent').children(2);`

Then append it to `partnerGroup` using `html`: `myColumn.html()`

I have updated your fiddle to show the content updating underneath:

http://jsfiddle.net/kL3c8/5/

Comment: @Alex - You need myColumn.html() not myColumn.  `html` is a function that returns the markup.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: @DarrenDavies LOL your answer popped up as I was answering, too fast is Dazefs ;)

Comment: @mattytommo - you're hitting 26 soon, must be the old age catching up ;)

Comment: @DarrenDavies definitely ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var rowCount = 2

var myColumn = $('.partnerGroupContent > :nth-child(2)')

if (rowCount == 2) {

$('<div class="partnerGroupContent2"></div>').insertAfter('.partnerGroupContent').append(myColumn.clone());

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kL3c8/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Even you can get an array of all column div by

```
var rowCount = 2
var columnArray = $('div.partnerGroupContent > div');
```

and get a particular column div by it's array index

```
if (rowCount == 2) {
   var myColumn = $(divArray[rowCount-1]).html();
   $('.partnerGroupContent').after('<div class="partnerGroupContent2">' + myColumn +     '</div>');
}
```